# Jquery Autocomplete Not Filtering Results from Database

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have the following jquery which calls my database: The string that is returned is:

["APPLE","DELL","HP","MICROSOFT"]

```
$(function(){
  $("#id-make").autocomplete({
      source: "actions/autocomplete.asp?data=1",
      minLength: 2,
  });
 });
```

However, as I type, all results are shown:

[image]

Am I missing a parameter from the jquery to filter the results.

Thanks

Update for Caique:

This is the auto-complete asp code that creates the string. I need to call the database to build the string so that it is always up to date

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM it_asset_makes ORDER BY make ASC;"

        Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rst.CursorLocation = 3
        rst.Open sSQL, Conn, 3, 1

        output = "["

        DO Until rst.EOF
        output = output & chr(34) & rst("make") & chr(34) & ","
        rst.movenext
        Loop

        output = left(output,(len(output)-1))
        output = output & "]"

        Response.Write output
```

output= ["APPLE","DELL","HP","MICROSOFT"]

```
<input type="text" class="form-box-wide" id="id-make" name="frm-make" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

its necessary pass data=1 in source?
Can you show us your html code and autocomplete.asp?

Html:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" name="id-make" id="id-make" value="" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
      var dataSource = ["APPLE","DELL","HP","MICROSOFT"];
    $("#id-make").autocomplete({
      source: dataSource,
      minLength: 2,
    });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fmvc14fj/2/